# Need help to recover files from .besub file extension

Tags: python, filesystems, software-rec, file-extension

I trying to learn python coding and i found a file extension (.besub) has change the python files as in figure attached and can not open.Please help to recover it.

[image]

Comment: You might get lucky on this one, a recent ransomware variant - see http://www.myantispyware.com/2019/07/03/besub-file-extension-ransomware-virus-restore-decrypt-besub-files/ but **don't** pay anyone any money.

Comment: Thank you for the update

Answer (score 1):

You are infected with the
[.Besub file extension ransomware virus](http://www.myantispyware.com/2019/07/03/besub-file-extension-ransomware-virus-restore-decrypt-besub-files/).
Your files have been encrypted (destroyed) and a ransom will be demanded.

DO NOT PAY, but immediately run anti-virus scans with your installed antivirus
and [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/).

See the following article:

[STOP Ransomware (.STOP, .Puma, .Djvu, .Promo, .Drume) Help & Support Topic](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/671473/stop-ransomware-stop-puma-djvu-promo-drume-support-topic)

Comment: Thank you for the update